# Smooth mapping from 2-torus to 2-sphere with constant jacobian

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, curvature

Is there a smooth area-preserving (i.e. unit jacobian) mapping from the 2-torus to the 2-sphere, or can we prove it's not possible?

While we can glue together two maps of the form $$f(x,y) = (\sqrt{1-y^2}\cos x, \sqrt{1-y^2}\sin x, y)$$ to define a *continuous* such mapping, with non-differentiability in the $y$ coordinate, I suspect the answer is *no* for a smooth mapping. Intuitively I think such a smooth mapping would be in contradiction with the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but I can't make this precise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the Jacobian of a smooth map $T^2 \to S^2$ were nonzero everywhere then that map would be a local diffeomorphism and hence (using compactness) a covering map. Since $S^2$ is simply connected, every smooth covering map to $S^2$ with connected domain is a diffeomorphism. But $T^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. I'd like to know how "close" we can get to a smooth unit-Jacobian mapping. Is it correct that Gauss-Bonnet implies the integral of the Jacobian over the torus is zero, and this is the only constraint on a smooth map $T^2\to S^2$?

Comment: That sounds incorrect to me. Briefly, the integrand in the Gauss-Bonnet theorem has a factor of Gaussian curvature that you seem to be ignoring. Regarding your interest in "how close", if you can formulate a precise question along those lines then that might be appropriate for posting a new question.